# Confusion Matrix - ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

For the sake of reproducibility, the training and validations datasets I am using are [shared here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-_dvey1kwLJoqfIdf4nxfkvWAqE1gL81?usp=sharing)

The `validation_dataset.csv` is the ground truth of `training_dataset.csv`.

What I am doing below is feeding the datasets into a simple CNN layer that extracts the useful features of the images and feed that as 1D into the LSTM network for classification.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score
from confusion_matrix import plot_confusion_matrix
import scikitplot as skplt
from numpy import genfromtxt

train_set = genfromtxt('data/train/training_dataset.csv', delimiter=',') 
validation_set = genfromtxt('data/validation/validation_dataset.csv', delimiter=',') 


train_set = train_set[..., None] 
validation_set = validation_set[..., None]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_set, validation_set, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)





    
batch_size=16
epochs=5

# Create the model
    
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(10))

model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae', 'mape', 'mean_squared_error', 'acc'])



model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)



print(model.summary())


# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))

skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, scores, x_tick_rotation=50, title=' ', normalize=True)
```

Finally, I want to plot the confusion matrix of the model using

`skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, scores, x_tick_rotation=50, title=' ', normalize=True)`

However, it is raising an error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5394, 5]`.

How can we fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` must be the predicted labels (see https://scikit-plot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metrics.html). But, you pass `scores`, which does not contain the predicted labels.

The fix would be to do:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test,
                                    y_pred,
                                    x_tick_rotation=50,
                                    title=' ',
                                    normalize=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jensun. But that throws this error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and continuous targets`

Comment: You should  then check the shapes of `y_pred` and `y_test`. `y_pred` must be of shape `(batch_size, )` or `(batch_size, 1)` in your case since you have a `Dense` layer with `1` unit at the very end. But, `y_test` is probably one-hot encoded targets. In that case you could do `y_test = numpy.argmax(y_test, axis=1)` before.

Comment: Thank you. After making `y_test = numpy.argmax(y_test, axis=1)`, both `y_pred` and `y_test` have the same shapes. However, I am still getting the same error:`ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous targets`

Comment: Hmm. That shouldn't happen as far as I know. Does `skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test, normalize=True)` work? You can also test with `skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_pred, normalize=True)`. Both should produce a confusion matrix with ones in the main diagonal.

Comment: `skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test, normalize=True)`is plotting the confusion matrix but not the kind of plot I wanted. `skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_pred, normalize=True)`is giving this error: `ValueError: continuous is not supported`

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at it again Jesun? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was working on SVM few days ago and when i tried to plot confusion matrix the following lines of code worked for me.

```
predicted=model.predict(X_test) #predicted output
cm=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted) 
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, range(2), range(2))
sns.set(font_scale=1.4) 
sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}) 
plt.title('CONFUSION MATRIX ',fontdict={'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight': 'bold'})
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Marcus I hope i will help you.

Comment: Thank you Hamza but it is giving an error: `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and continuous targets`